# downgrade .csproj from 2010 to 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

I've been working on a program in Visual Studio 2010. I'm still having compatibility issues I've mentioned here before.

Is there a way to downgrade my C# project so that I can open it with Visual Studio 2008 (without copying the code over and recreating the form)?

For those who'd like to know, the problem I'm having is some sort of unhandled exception as soon as the program runs on the Windows XP machine (it delivers the "send error report" window). I spoke to some people who suggested it might be a compatibility issue, so I thought I'd give that a try. I figured if I could get it to compile on Visual Studio 2008 on a Windows XP SP2 machine, it'd work on the necessary machine. If anyone has any suggestions as to what else the problem could be, that is also welcome.

Comment: What are the compatibility issues? Wouldn't targeting .NET Framework 3.5 or 2.0 be sufficient (which can be done from within VS 2010)?

Comment: I've tried this, but it did not solve the issue. I've even installed all versions of the .NET Framework (back to 3.0) and it didn't solve the problem. I figured if I could compile it right on the platform that is necessary for it to work on, then I could get it to work.

Comment: I agree with 0xA3: why don't you spell out the actual issues to see if the community can help you resolve them?  From reviewing your other questions it appears that the issues are not compatibility ones but rather problems you are having understanding the language which downgrading to 2008 won't help with...

Comment: @rar: I also checked your other question and I don't see any clue why downgrading to VS 2008 would solve anything. What problem are you actually facing?

Comment: @0xA3 I've updated the question to give details on my issue with the program.

Comment: @rar: First thing to check: Is the correct version of the .NET Framework installed? Then analyze the actual cause of the problem (i.e. what exception is being thrown). If your application is not multi-threaded wrap the main method in  a try/catch and add `Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());` or `MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());` to the catch block.

Comment: but what would you be trying to "catch"? (like what exception)?

Answer (score 3):

Give this a try:

[How to downgrade from Visual Studio 2010 project to VS 2008 or VS 2005?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsprereleaseannouncements/thread/4345a151-d288-48d6-b7c7-a7c598d0f85e)

Comment: this doesnt't detail how to downgrade a C++ project file

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to downgrade your project is opening you sln file with the editor and change the following things:

to play safe you should make a copy of your exisiting project and save it somewhere else.

1.) in the 1.line is somewhere "Format Version 11.00" --> change 11.00 to 10.00

2.) in the 2.line is "... Express 2010" change 2010 to 2008.

Save it and open with C#!

Answer (score 0):

With ease no...here is a [post](https://web.archive.org/web/20150624153201/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/rextang/archive/2009/07/06/9819189.aspx) on how it could possibly work. In addition if you have 4.0 features you will have to revert those to 3.5 syntax.